# How to assign a returned char pointer to an array

Tags: c, string, return-type

Im trying to return a pointer to a string in my function and assign to another char array to print it out. But i get a conflicting type error for my function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *s = "[[random text]]";

    const char *P1 = "[[";
    const char *P2 = "]]";
    const char *result = parseString(s,P1,P2);
    printf("%s",result);
} 

void const char* parseString(char* str,char* first, char* snd)
{
    char *target = NULL;
    char *start, *end;

    if ( start = strstr( str, first ) )
    {
        start += strlen( first );
        if ( end = strstr( start, snd ) )
        {
            target = ( char * )malloc( end - start + 1 );
            memcpy( target, start, end - start );
            target[end - start] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message as text (not as a screenshot) into the question. This error message should include a line number. You may want to quote the line of code that this error message is referring to, since Stack Overflow does not display line numbers.

Comment: Note that your code would be easier to read (both for yourself and for other people) if you used consistent indentation. I have fixed the indentation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the following problems:

1. You should provide a [prototype declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration) of the function `parseString` before using it in `main`.
2. If you want the function `parseString` to return a pointer to a string, then you should make the return type of the function `char *` instead of `void const char*`.
3. If you declare the parameters of the function `parseString` to be of type `char*`, then you are not allowed to pass that function an argument of type `const char *`. However, since the function `parseString` does not modify the strings pointed to by its arguments, you can declare the parameters to be `const char *` instead of `char *`, which will solve your problem.

After fixing these issues, your could will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* parseString( const char* str, const char* first, const char* snd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *s = "[[random text]]";

    const char *P1 = "[[";
    const char *P2 = "]]";
    const char *result = parseString(s,P1,P2);
    printf("%s",result);
} 

char* parseString( const char* str, const char* first, const char* snd)
{
    char *target = NULL;
    char *start, *end;

    if ( start = strstr( str, first ) )
    {
        start += strlen( first );
        if ( end = strstr( start, snd ) )
        {
            target = ( char * )malloc( end - start + 1 );
            memcpy( target, start, end - start );
            target[end - start] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```